# Special Character in Git possible?

Tags: git

I was really happy I fixed this stupid bug in my rails code and I happily typed the following into terminal:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Finally fixed that difficult bug!"
```

Only to find out that git doesn't like "!". Does anyone know of a way I can get it into my commit message?

Comment: Assuming you're not creating a new file, you don't need both a "git add" and a "commit -a"

Comment: I'm not certain that Git appreciated `f*cking` either :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: I voted that way because although they aren't exact Q's, this question was closed as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033158/use-of-apostrophe-single-quote-in-a-git-commit-message-via-command-line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass argument with exclamation mark on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346502/how-to-pass-argument-with-exclamation-mark-on-linux)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use single quotes. I don't know why it doesn't work in double quotes. It's actually a problem with your shell rather than git, in bash it has to do with command history.

You can also leave out the 'm' option and enter your commit message in your editor. That way you don't ever have to worry about escaping.

Comment: Double quotes allow most expansions.  The purpose is to group into a single argument.

Comment: When I used single quotes I was able to use the exclamation point. I don't think its possible with a single line, but this definitely answers the question.

Answer (score 14):

! is the "History expansion" character in Bash, and it is the shell that is causing this character to foul up.

See section: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Subsection: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes

(Use a \! )

Comment: Well I did that -- but it seems that git also escaped the backslash :( . So I ended up with a commit message of `Removing stupid stuff\! `

Comment: `(Use a \! )` - or just use single quotes.