# How to escape '@' within username or password for git url's

Tags: git

One of the formats for pushing to git on command line is

```
Url format:
    https://{username:password@}github.com/{owner}/{repo}
```

My challenge is the username and password - which are for a shared account I do not control - contain the `@` within them (both actually ..)

What would be my options in this case (and *not* to change the username, password - that will take some additional administrative/coordination steps).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457009/special-character-in-git-possible) will help.  For reference, could you show us an actual command which is failing?

Comment: Consider finding a way to access the account that doesn't require including the password as plain text in a URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try percent-encoding the `@` characters:

```
https://usern%40me:p%40ssword@github.com/owner/repo
```

Comment: Note: if used within a batch file the %-character need to be escaped too.
so the string would look like this:
https://usern%%40me:p%%40ssword@github.com/owner/repo

Answer (score 3):

Would url ecoding work? Eg @ = %40

Ref [Url encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Ps different languages encode @ differently. (Eg Javascript)

All the best