# How to have git store ONLY my username and not my password?

Tags: git

I am aware that I can use git config credential.helper to store both my username and password. But I want to ONLY store my username and have the terminal ask for my password each time I push. How is this done?

Something similar to this, but without the password.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

Comment: this might help you https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: As far as a literal answer to the question, I would second brian m carlson's answer below.  (I was writing a similar answer, but am not where I can test to verify it, and couldn't find appropriate documentation references to back it up for protocols other than ssh.  But as it seems to be an answer several are coming to, I trust that it's right.)  That said: I'm curious why you want to do it this way?  Compared to a proper no-password-entry solution, this is less secure in practice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git credential helpers store both usernames and passwords. The design is such that if a username and password combination succeed, then the helper is told to write both items to its store.

If you want to store only the username, and not the password, then you shouldn't use a credential helper. Instead, you should disable the credential helper and write the username in the URL for the remote. For example, you can use `git remote set-url origin http://minyc510@example.com/repo.git` to set the remote URL for origin to contain your username. Note that if your username contains characters outside of letters and numbers, it may need to be percent-escaped.

Comment: For the common case of signing in with Mail, replace the `@` by `%40`; see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450667/6950750

Comment: This was the right answer for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487979/170403