# bash escape exclamation character inside variable with backtick

Tags: linux, bash

I have this bash script:

```
databases=`mysql -h$DBHOST -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`
```

and the issue is when the password has all the characters possible. how can i escape the `$DBPASSWORD` in this case? If I have a password with '!' and given the fact that command is inside backticks. I have no experience in bash scripts but I've tried with `"$DBPASSWORD"` and with `'$DBPASSWORD'` and it doesn't work. Thank you

LATER EDIT: link to script here, line 170 -> https://github.com/Ardakilic/backmeup/blob/master/backmeup.sh

Comment: `!` doesn't actually need to be escaped.

Comment: Run your script through http://shellcheck.net/, and fix everything it finds.

Comment: (BTW, all-caps names are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use to avoid conflicts; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: Also, backticks in shell have been deprecated for new development literally for decades (the POSIX sh standard came out, making `$()` syntax a formal requirement for compliant shells, in 1991). The `$()` syntax is easier to nest, and it doesn't mess with backslashes inside your commands so enclosed.

Comment: Lots and lots of quoting bugs. `rm $1/backmeup*`, for instance, will behave very surprisingly if your `$1` is a directory name with spaces in it. `"$1"/backmeup*` -- quoting the expansion but not the glob -- is the Right Thing.

Comment: I know, like aside joke, when i run the script it is automatically deleting it self ... but I am editing the stuff. I am using only the mysql thing and 2 other commands ... but what can I do? I want to know how to do it :)

Comment: `"$foo"` correctly passes the precise value of the variable `foo` for **every possible variable** that does not contain NULs (and a variable containing NULs is literally impossible, since bash variables are C strings, same as `argv` entries). This is easily proven, if such proof is needed. Literally every byte other than a NUL can be passed in this way.

Comment: ...consequently, the claim that an exclamation mark stored in a variable not expanding correctly is the cause of your problem is hard to treat credibly.

Comment: You want to know how to do it? Keep doing exactly what you're doing: trying, failing, asking questions. Eventually you'll intuit this stuff.

Comment: ...btw, to log enough detail to allow debugging: `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript 2>/path/to/logfile` will put the exact commands invoked in your logfile (as well as the rest of stderr output). That log would probably do a lot of good in terms of helping to generate a question more effectively focused on the immediate point of failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass argument with exclamation mark on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3346502/608639)

Answer (score 4):

First: The [answer from @bishop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42629315/14122) is spot on: **Don't pass passwords on the command line.**

Second: Use double quotes for all shell expansions. *All of them*. Always.

```
databases=$(mysql -h"$DBHOST" -u"$DBUSER" -p"$DBPASSWORD" -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it didn't work ... just to get clear, I've searched a script to put it on a cronjob to make automated backups for the DB and I found this script (see the link) and I have this password with `!` ... from my perspective I just need to know if this is possible or not with this script and literally on the case I think it is but i don't know the way

Comment: It absolutely does work in the sense that the password gets passed to `mysql`, so long as `DBPASSWORD` is correctly populated to start with. What mysql does with it past that point is an open question, and likewise is whether the value is being correctly populated. Use `set -x` to log commands as they're run.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass the MySQL password on the command line. One, it can be tricky with passwords containing shell meta-characters (as you've discovered). Two, importantly, someone using `ps` can sniff the password.

Instead, either put the password into the system `my.cnf`, your user configuration file (eg `.mylogin.cnf`) or create an on-demand file to hold the password:

```
function mysql() {
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    cat > "$tmpfile" <<EOCNF
[client]
password=$DBPASSWORD
EOCNF
    mysql --defaults-extra-file="$tmpfile" -u"$DBUSER" -h"$DBHOST" "$@"
    rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

Then you can run it as:

```
mysql -e "SHOW DATABASES" | tr -d "| " ....
mysql -e "SELECT * FROM table" | grep -v ...
```

See the [MySQL docs on configuration files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) for further examples.

Comment: I know to not but passwords in the command line, but im my case I am getting the password from a file into this bash script. so no `ps` available here. The issue is if I have a password that has ! how do I escape it? it is coming like a string so I can't modify the string, just escape.

Comment: You are wrong: bash forks mysql and, guess what, your password is right there in the process table. Change your SQL to `SLEEP(100)` for proof.

Comment: ok, I can agree that I am wrong, but the issue is not the mysql safety now, is the character escaping from backticks ... any idea on that?

Comment: see the script here -> https://github.com/Ardakilic/backmeup/blob/master/backmeup.sh line 170

Comment: Escaping solves the wrong problem. The actual problem is getting mysql client to accept your password. Do so safely and unambiguously with config files.

Comment: ok, I will give it a try and get back on this. for me is surprising that if I type in the command in bash it is working perfectly

Comment: Behavior differing between cron and interactive shells in utterly unsurprising -- lots of variances. Environment variables set by your `.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile` and similar as a user aren't available; there's typically a much more restrictive default PATH; the direct command given in the crontab is interpreted by `/bin/sh` rather than bash; etc. But none of those variances will cause exclamation marks to be treated differently inside a quoted variable expansion, which is part of why the suggestion that they *are* is being taken with such skepticism.

Comment: (History expansion will make a leading `!` mean something utterly unlike its usual behavior, but that's (1) off-by-default in noninteractive shells, and (2) isn't invoked on expansion results even when it's enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the same problem when automating activities:

- I have a variable containing a string (usually a password) that is set in a config file or passed on the command-line, and that string includes the '`!`' character.
- I need to pass that variable's value to another program, as a command-line argument.
- If I pass the variable unquoted, or in double-quotes (`"$password"`), the shell tries to interpret the '`!`', which fails.
- If I pass the variable in single quotes (`'$password'`), the variable isn't expanded.

One solution is to construct the full command in a variable and then use `eval`, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
username=myuser
password='my_pass!'
cmd="/usr/bin/someprog -user '$username' -pass '$password'"
eval "$cmd"
```

Another solution is to write the command to a temporary file and then `source` the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
username=myuser
password='my_pass!'
cmd_tmp=$HOME/.tmp.$$
touch $cmd_tmp
chmod 600 $cmd_tmp
cat > $cmd_tmp <<END
/usr/bin/someprog -user '$username' -pass '$password'
END
source $cmd_tmp
rm -f $cmd_tmp
```

Using `eval` is simple, but writing a file allows for multiple complex commands.

P.S. Yes, I know that passing passwords on the command-line isn't secure - there is no need for more virtue-signalling comments on that topic.