# Execute a script through ssh and store its pid in a file on the remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, pid, nohup

I am not able to store any `PID` in a file on the remote machine when running a script in background through ssh.

I need to store the `PID` of the script process in a file in purpose to kill it whenever needed. When running the exact command on the remote machine it is working, why through ssh it is not working so ?

What is wrong with the following command:

```sh
ssh user@remote_machine "nohup ./script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > ./pid.log"
```

Result: The file `pid.log` is created but empty.

Expected: The file `pid.log` should contain the `PID` of the running script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass argument with exclamation mark on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3346502/608639), [bash escape exclamation character inside variable with backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42628841/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ssh user@remote_machine 'nohup ./script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > ./pid.log'
```

OR

```
ssh user@remote_machine "nohup ./script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$! > ./pid.log"
```

Issue:
[Your `$!` was getting expanded locally, before calling ssh at all.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2029)

Worse, before calling the ssh command, if there was a process stared in the background, then `$!` would have expanded to that and complete ssh command would have got expanded to contain that PID as argument to echo.

e.g.

```
$ ls &
[12342] <~~~~ This is the PID of ls
$ <~~~~ Prompt returns immediately because ls was stared in background. 
myfile1 myfile2 <~~~~ Output of ls.
[1]+  Done                    ls
#### At this point, $! contains 12342
$ ssh user@remote "command & echo $! > pidfile"
# before even calling ssh, shell internally expands it to:
$ ssh user@remote "command & echo 12342 > pidfile"
```

And it will put the wrong PID in the pidfile.

Comment: Thank you @anishsane ! That was indeed my issue :)